# Manually edit the html of "Thumbnail grid with expanding preview" / Change the .js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just used this tutorial with a thumbnail grid with expanding preview: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

This works with a javascript generatet html-code for the content of the expanding preview. So I can't manually edit the html for the box, I only can fill in title, description, image and link.

Is there an easy way to change the .js file, that I always have to edit the html for the box manually? 
As an expample, it would be like this in the html file:

```
<li>
     <a href="#">
          <img src="img/thumbnail1.png" alt="img01"/>
     </a>
     <div>
          Content
     </div>
 </li>
```

And in this div is the content of the box, that appears on click.

Thanks for your help!

Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can definatly do that by easily changing function which is responsible for rendering detail page.

```
Preview.prototype = {
    create : function() {
        // create Preview structure:
        this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
        this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
        this.$href = $( '<a href="#">Visit website</a>' );
        this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href );
        this.$myDiv = $( '<div class="my-div"></div>' ).append( "My Injected DIVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV" );
        this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
        this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
        this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
        this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$myDiv,this.$details);
        this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
        // append preview element to the item
        this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
        // set the transitions for the preview and the item
        if( support ) {
            this.setTransition();
        }
    },
```

Check out how I have injected new div and it is visible on details page as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But is it possible to edit the html of every single box manually. So in every box is another html code?

Comment: No, the reason is those htmls divs are generated through js dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But you can't write in the .js that it should take the content of a div from an unvisible div in the html?

Comment: Or is it possible to rewrite the full js, so that it's just the animation and you can fill it manually?

Comment: It is possible to keep it editable.    this.$myDiv = $( '<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>' ).append( "My Injected DIVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV" );